# Creating class object from pandas series and applying methods

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that reads in a bunch of raw data with some user-input and compiles it into a Pandas series. In the example below I call it `create_data` and it just builds a random Series of length `n`.

```
>>> def create_data(n):
...     return pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, n))
... 
>>> 
>>> function_result=create_data(10)
>>> function_result
0    73
1    91
2    31
3    44
4    19
5    30
6    42
7    56
8    69
9    70
dtype: int32
```

Then I have a set of functions that want to be able to apply to this series. In this example, I create one that calculates the correlation between the series and its first-degree difference.

```
>>> def temporal_corr(x):
...     return pd.concat([x, x.shift()], 1).corr().iloc[0, 1]
...
```

I can obviously just apply it to series by calling the function...

```
>>> temporal_corr(function_result)
0.38714413906049816
```

But let's say I have several different functions that I want to use on this series. Would it make more sense (or is it possible), to create a class that constructs an object using the function `create_data` and then have a set of functions within the class that can be applied as methods? I create a class and define this function below.

```
>>> class myobj:
...     def __init__(self, myobj):
...         self.myobj = myobj
...     
...     def temporal_corr(self):
...         return pd.concat([self.myobj, self.myobj.shift()], 1).corr().iloc[0, 1]
... 
>>> a = myobj(function_result)
>>> a.temporal_corr()
0.38714413906049816
```

What is the best way to have the class object `myobj` be created as a result of the function `create_data`? I would like to be able to call `create_data` and have the result be an object from which I can call `temporal_corr()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. If you want `create_data` to return a `myobj` instance, why not just do that: `def create_data(n): return myobj(pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, n)))`

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? It makes the code more complicated with no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class MyObjMaker(object):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.myobj = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, n))

    def temporal_corr(self):
        return pd.concat([self.myobj, self.myobj.shift()], 1).corr().iloc[0, 1]


def create_data(n):
    return MyObjMaker(n)
```

Here, the function `create_data` creates an object from the class, and that has your `temporal_corr` function. For example, I'd use it as follows:

```
In [2]: a = create_data(10)  # `a` is now an instance of MyObjMaker

In [4]: type(a)  # proof that `a` is now an instance of MyObjMaker
Out[4]: __main__.MyObjMaker

In [5]: a.temporal_corr()  # `temporal_corr` works
Out[5]: -0.18294239972101703
```

Jim's solution should be fine too, but it sub-classes off of `pd.Series` - if you don't need all the other methods in `pd.Series` then there's no point sub-classing off of it.

Comment: If you have just the `__init__()`, encapsulate one value, and have one method like this, you don't have a class. It's just a function written in an overcomplicated way. What is this construct ment so solve? `create_data()` also doesn't make sense. The effect of that function is just an alias of `MyObjMaker` which can be written simpler as `create_data = MyObjMaker` — or left out entirely.

Comment: @BlackJack if you read the Q/A carefully, this is what the asker was lookg to solve. It's not my place to wonder why they're doing something a certain way, as this question was very specific and not about Python and Pythonic style. Also, your `create_data = MyObjMaker` is incorrect. This would make `create_data` a `class` as well. The way I have it, it returns a guaranteed instance of type `MyObjMaker`.

Comment: The comment has nothing to do with Python or style. It just doesn't make sense to dress up a simple function as a useless class, unless the language forces you to, like Java (before lambda expressions maybe). How would my simpler definition of `create_data` return a different instance? Maybe when `MyObjMaker` implements `__new__()`, but that would affect your function in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you're looking for an object that acts like a `Series` but is more *specialized*, so, just create a class that inherits from `pd.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint

class mySeries(pd.Series):

    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__(randint(0, 100, n))  # initialize series

    # Add your custom methods:
    def temporal_corr(self):
        return pd.concat([self, self.shift()], 1).corr().iloc[0, 1]
```

Then, `create_data` can be your factory function for your specialized `Series` objects:

```
def create_data(n):
    return mySeries(n)
```

which you can extend and add checks according to your needs.